# Android: How to get JSON object from Zomato API?

Tags: android, curl, zomato-api

My goal is to display a list of nearby restaurants using the Zomato API. I first need the JSON object to get the names of these restaurants.
I've already got the API key and I know that the request URL would look like this

```
https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/search?lat=LATITUDE&lon=LONGITUDE
```

From the documentation https://developers.zomato.com/documentation, it seems that I have to use something called *Curl* but I don't know what Curl is.

```
curl -X GET --header "Accept: application/json" --header "user-key: API key" "https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/search?&lat=LATITUDE&lon=LONGITUDE"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that the Curl contained `--header` so I did some research about headers in URLs and added these 2 lines after `url.openConnection();`

```
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", " application/json");
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("user-key", " "+API_KEY);
```

And I got what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Rest Client to call the request with the header and URL.
I suggest using [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) or [Retrofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit) to do it.
Here is an example using Volley:

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String url = "https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/search?&lat=27&lon=153";
        JsonObjectRequest postRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        // response
                        Log.d("Response", response.toString());
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Log.d("ERROR", "error => " + error.toString());
                    }
                }
        ) {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("user-key", "55a1d18014dd0c0dac534c02598a3368");
                params.put("Accept", "application/json");

                return params;
            }
        };
        queue.add(postRequest);
```

And the response I've got:

```
{"restaurants":[],"results_found":0,"results_shown":0,"results_start":0}
```